# How to work with youtube dl android library

Tags: android, rx-java, youtube-dl

here is the link to my gist https://gist.github.com/tomleejumah/d11d1996bce8957c140c90e7856e01eb
I do have a bug in fetching whereby it doesnt fetch
Im requesting help in debugging